# Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type- React

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React app that lists which of your plants need watering based on data from the database and I'm getting this error with my onClick:
`` Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type `` 
I researched it and as far as I can tell I'm calling a function, what am I missing?  Am I calling the onClick the correct way?  Thanks so much for reading!

From `<WaterList />` component:

```
// This will update the waterDate
function handleUpdate(id) {
  setUpdatedItem((prevInput) => {
    return {
      ...prevInput,
      waterDate: {newWaterDate}
    }
  })
  submitData(id);
  console.log(updatedItem);
}
```

```
return (
   <div className="water-list">
     <h2>Water Me!</h2>
     <p>check off to reset water schedule and remove from list</p>
     <ul className="water-list__plants">
       { waterList(plants).map(plant =>
         <li key={plant._id}>
           <Plant name={plant.name} img={plant.img} waterFrequency={plant.waterFrequency} onClick={() => handleUpdate(plant._id)}></Plant>
         </li>) }
     </ul>
   </div>
 );
```

From `<Plant />` single list item component:

```
const Plant = (props) => (
  <li className="plant" id={props._id}>
    <div className="plant__img-wrapper">
      <img
        src={props.img}
        alt={props.name}
        className="plant__img"
      />
    </div>
    <div className="plant__text-wrapper">
      <h3 className="plant__name">{props.name}</h3>
      <p>Water me every {props.waterFrequency} days, please</p>
    </div>
    <label className="plant__care-form">
      <input onClick="{ () => handleUpdate(props._id) }" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-check" />
    </label>
  </li>
);
```

Comment: In plant component, u gave onClick handler inside string                                                              `<input onClick={ () => handleUpdate(props._id) } type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />`

Comment: This is a string : `onClick="{ () => handleUpdate(props._id) }" `

Comment: oh my gosh.  Thank you.  I can't believe I did that, I was questioning everything.